# Copy the last seen non empty value of a column based on a condition in most efficient way in Pandas/Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to copy and paste the previous non-empty value of a column based on a condition. I need to do it in the most efficient way because the number of rows is a couple of millions. Using `for loop` will be computationally costly.

So it will be highly appreciated if somebody can help me in this regard.

```
|Col_A   |Col_B   |
|--------|--------|
|10.2.6.1| NaN    |
|  NaN   | 51     |
|  NaN   | NaN    |
|10.2.6.1| NaN    |
|  NaN   | 64     |
|  NaN   | NaN    |
|  NaN   | NaN    |
|10.2.6.1| NaN    |
```

Based on the condition, whenever the `Col_A` will have any value (not null) 10.2.6.1 in this example, the last seen value in `Col_B` `(51...64 respectively)` will be paste on that corresponding row where the `Col_A` value is not null. And the dataset should look like this:

```
|Col_A   |Col_B   |
|--------|--------|
|10.2.6.1| NaN    |
|  NaN   | 51     |
|  NaN   | NaN    |
|10.2.6.1| 51     |
|  NaN   | 64     |
|  NaN   | NaN    |
|  NaN   | NaN    |
|10.2.6.1| 64     |
```

I tried with this code below but it's not working:

```
df.loc[df["Col_A"].notnull(),'Col_B'] = df.loc[df["Col_B"].notnull(),'Col_B']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can forward-fill the NaN values using [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) with the most recent non-NaN value.

If you want to keep the NaNs in `Col_B` then simply create a new column (`Col_C`) as follows:

```
df['Col_C'] = df['Col_B'].ffill()
```

Then replace the value in `Col_B` where `Col_A` has a value:

```
df.loc[df['Col_A'].notnull(), 'Col_B'] = df.loc[df['Col_A'].notnull(), 'Col_C']
df = df.drop(columns=['Col_C'])
```

Result:

```
       Col_A    Col_B
0   10.2.6.1      NaN
1        NaN     51.0
2        NaN      NaN
3   10.2.6.1     51.0
4        NaN     64.0
5        NaN      NaN
6        NaN      NaN
7   10.2.6.1     64.0
```

---

The above can be simplified if you do not need to keep all NaN rows. For example, it's possible to do:

```
df['Col_B'] = df['Col_B'].ffill()
df = df.dropna()
```

Result:

```
       Col_A    Col_B
3   10.2.6.1     51.0
7   10.2.6.1     64.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! YES, it's working properly and it is very fast.

Comment: By the way, are there any other alternatives without copying my contents(Col_B) in another dummy column (Col_C) and deleting it later on?

Comment: @DarkStar: I can't think of any good approach except for doing `ffill` directly on `Col_B` as the simplified method in the answer. The use of an additional column that is deleted should be relatively fast and does not have too much overhead.